# Change Tag of Instantiated Clone

Tags: c#, unity

In my game there is a bird flying up and a stream of containers (baskets) is moving from right to left of the screen in the bottom. Baskets are being `Instantiated` on right and get destroyed when they reach the left side of the screen.

 On The left there is an `EmptyObject` called Destroyer and anything that `collides` with it get destroyed. I'm not using out of bounds for the objects to get destroyed instead I'm using an `EmptyObject` with collide.

 And on tap the bird throws an artifact `projectile` downwards and if it collides with the Basket it changes into another sprite. This is the code for that `transform.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = changedBasket;`

 The problem is that user is only allowed to miss `3` baskets losing more than `3` baskets will result in Game Over. So inside my `Basket.cs` I'm checking that `if(target.gameObject.tag == "Deadly")` then count it as a chance loose. **BUT** the `changeBasket` also act as it's the same basket.
The logic that I think will work is to change the `tag` after the artifact `collides` with the basket and on that type of tagged object deadly won't work. If I'm write kindly tell me how to implement this in `c#` of-course. Please note that the object is an `Instantiated Clone`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this [rapid google search](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/solved-how-to-set-a-gameobject-tag-through-a-script.56581/) states:

```
gameObject.tag="new_tag";
```

Obviously your "new_tag" has to exist inside the editor.